# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':enclave:compileJava'

Tags: kotlin, gradle, sgx, enclave, conclave

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':enclave:compileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve project :common.

```
 Required by:
     project :enclave
  > No matching variant of project :common was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, and its dependencies declared externally but:
      - Variant 'apiElements' capability column-profiling:common:unspecified declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 14 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
      - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability column-profiling:common:unspecified declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 14 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
```

Tried to run column-profiling conclave and received error message
https://github.com/r3conclave/conclave-samples

Comment: Please provide a full example, without it it's impossible to know what's wrong

Comment: the build script is expecting to have a project called common which it can't find.  Check that its there, and under your root project folder.  It may need to be checked out separately, check for any README files or build instructions.

Comment: I can see you are running against Java14. Can you set your Java JDK to 1.8 and then try running again?

Answer (score 0):

Adding sourceCompatibility = 1.8 to build.gradle in common project should fix this issue. I will update the sample with the same.